# How can I manage interdependencies in a software test environment?

Tags: linux, version

We've got a large and complex test environment in which various product groups test their software before rolling out a new release. One of the challenges to this process is that different product teams may expect differing versions of components in the software environment in order to do their tests (we're trying to fix this in the long term, but that's how it is now).

Currently, the conflicts between the different product teams are managed in a spreadsheet by a test environment coordinator, however, this is becoming burdensome and we're exploring potential open source solutions to this problem, such as constraint management or scheduling software.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?, if so, what tools did you use to meet your requirements?

Comment: This is a really well written question so I hate to voteclose it but it's really a recommendation/opinion-based question to me.  You should try bringing this up in chat, though.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was concerned about that aspect of the question, was just trying a shot in the dark :|